# LVDS length pair matching (HSD connectors)

Tags: connector, lvds

For a high speed interconnect (3 - 6GBit/sec over a single lvds pair) I attempted to length match the LVDS data pair as accurate as possible. Something I have failed to get information on is the length matching including the connector conductor geometry.   (ignoring the cable for now, as the cable is a shielded twisted pair , non-cross-over type)

Simple questions regarding propagation delay differnce between pins within HSD style connectors I received irrelvant responses from the 'big' connector manufacturers.

How would I realize perfect length matching within a single LVDS pair without getting information from the manufacturer?  (I dont have access to a TDR with ps resolution)

Edit:
The Connector intended for use is a Right-Angle type.  The Right-Angle construction physically has a longer and shorter conductor for a single data pair. Data Pairs are crossed diagonally, causing right-angle connectors always to have a longer path and shorter path within an data pair.

Today I found out by another HSD connector manufacturer that specifies its propagation time for the signals as in skew with a data pair. According to HSD documentation by T.E.: data pair skew may be <25ps for right angle connectors, and <5ps for straight connectors..

No absolutes or window of ranges are given, is the safe assumption of 24ps skew valid?

Reference:  https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-1-2286546-5.html

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE - do you have a typical connector you are trying to use? That will make the question more complete.

Comment: Thank you. I complemented the question with additional & new data.